# Apache rewrite rule to add a directory in front of a file

Tags: seo, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an HTML page in my root directory, and when someone clicks it I'd like there to be a  directory before the file name, that doesn't exist.

For example, instead of just being able to access:

> wwww.example.com/link.html

This would also work:

> wwww.example.com/**folder**/link.html

Can this be done with a rewrite rule?

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit more? Do you mean they'd click a link to `wwww.example.com/link.html` but be forwarded to `wwww.example.com/folder/link.html`? And what's not created, the directory `/folder`?

Comment: yes, i just want it as you you'd see in wordpress links etc

Comment: I have some URLS and I want to add a a specific word before the link.html so its like a keyword 
e.g. 
www.example.com/townname/link.html www.example.com/townname/link2.html

can that not be done with a rewrite rule / permalink?

Comment: Edited your question based on your comments and reopened it.

Comment: The functionality of mod rewrite per the wordpress and other CMS application is not to serve as such a redirect, but instead in order to "prettify" otherwise abstract linkage because the site is database driven. A common URL for a CMS would be example.com/index.php?page=somepageid.  The rewrite rule is designed to make a pretty url that is SEO friendly. What is your purpose in trying to use this? Adding a non-existant directory to the URL is only going to break several web standards, and potentially confuse your visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule (appropriate for a *.htaccess* file) would look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/link.html$ /link.html
```

That would serve the contents of `link.html` at both `/link.html` and `/folder/link.html`.